# Uploading Files to Google Drive using Rest API: cannot set name

Tags: rest, post, google-drive-api, postman

I'm beginning with Google Drive REST API. I'm building an android app that has to upload .txt and .pdf files to google Drive. I managed to get my Oauth2.0 credentials using Google Cloud console. 
I wanted to try if I was able to upload a .txt file so I follow this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfaGPh0YioE

I'm using Postman with the same configuration of this video. The problem is, when I send a POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files`, the files uploads but without any metadata (I can't set the name nor `mimeType`, just see "untitled" files). What I am doing wrong?

I wrote different `.json` files (attached to this question) to see if it changes, but It is always the same result.

First try:

```
{
    "name": "prueba.txt",
    "mimeType": "text/plain"
}
```

Second try:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [Auth token]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: text/plain
X-Upload-Content-Length: 1000

{
  "name": "prueba.txt",
  "mimeType": "text/plain"
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I have several questions. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is the difference between "First try" and "Second try"? 2. Do you want to use the resumable upload? 3. How much size is the file of?

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Sorry if make question wasn't so clear! In Postman, in the body of my POST request, I attached a json file to set the metadata and the textfile itself. At first I tried with the json that was in the video. The second try was with the json written in Google Drive Rest api example. Both tries failed. This file it's just 1kb and yes, I want to use resumable upload. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to use the resumable upload, I think that this official document is useful. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I tried but It still not work. I attatch you a link to my drive where you can see the files related. https://1drv.ms/f/s!Arwn1F2Qb7hslq4jJ-3BPtK6Oe1XKQ

Comment: Thank you for replying. I checked the link. But unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation from the files in the link. I apologize for my poor skill.